Manhwa where Fl is a genius with medicinal herbs but hides it so she doesn’t have to work hard
I read this awhile ago so I don’t remember much but there is a scene where a girl who bullied her is using a face cream to make herself more beautiful but the Fl reveals that it will soon melt her face off if she doesn’t stop using it. The bully soon faces these consequences and is crying in the nurses office when the Fl comes in and gives her the cure. I’m pretty sure it’s a romance but am really struggling to remember much else. Oh! There also might have been an overworked lab assistant that kept trying to get the Fl help.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Also, are the herbs magical or something?  If this is just set in the real world then it's not on-topic as works need to include science fictional or fantastic elements to be asked about here.

Apothecary Diaries matches the question title, and has an opening plot about toxic face cream, but it's a manga instead of a manhua and it otherwise doesn't appear to match what you're looking for

I think it’s I Swear We’re Just Friends

When Rienne transfers to the elite Alena Academy, she never expects Karcion, the most popular mage in school, to recruit her into his club... and she definitely doesn't think he'll fall for her! But the grumpy Karcion soon makes it clear how much he adores her, and she starts finding him too cute to ignore. Still, he's a future duke and she's a commoner, so Rienne knows his feelings won't last. Can Karcion magic his way out of the friendzone? Or will Rienne prove they're just friends after all?


I am currently reading it. There is face melting in chapter 28 and the girl she helps is called prattling tater (a nickname from the fl) or PT for short. Also the lab assistant is one of her teachers who works for her homeroom (?) professor. The whole reason she avoids him is to not become an overworked lab assistant. She uses Karcion (Kar for short) and Fior’s club room to nap in, as well as hide, and she enjoys teasing Kar to see his reactions.
